# Advice for this P-Channel MOSFET Power Source Selector

Tags: arduino, power-supply, mosfet, circuit-analysis, arduino-uno

I know there are already questions and answers about P-Channel MOSFETs and power source selection, but I still find myself pretty confused, as many of those are more complex than my circuit or simply connected differently. I'll lay out my design and then list a few questions. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

I'm powering an ATMEGA328P using approximately 5V (so it can run at 16MHz). Normally, it will run on 3 AAAs in series (4.5V total). When I connect a 5V FTDI USB-to-serial board to program it, I'd like power from the battery to be cut to keep from damaging the battery (I don't want to have to put a diode there). I'm planning to use a logic-level P-Channel MOSFET. I expect to draw about 50mA max, but may plan for 100mA just to be safe.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcg0Ir.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Analysis:

```
Vusb range: [4.75V, 5.25V] (per USB standards)
Vbat range: [3.8V, 4.8V] (min needed for 16MHz and max from 1.6V AAA estimated max voltage)

USB Connected:

Vusb    Vbat    Vgs    Expected MOSFET State
--------------------------------------------
4.75V   3.8V    0.95V  OFF
4.75V   4.8V   -0.05V  OFF
5.25V   3.8V    1.45V  OFF
5.25V   4.8V    0.45V  OFF

USB Disconnected:

Vusb    Vbat    Vgs    Expected MOSFET State
--------------------------------------------
0V      3.8V   -3.8V   ON
0V      4.8V   -4.8V   ON
```

Questions:

- Are there any glaring mistakes with this design?
- What's the best way to keep the MOSFET from accidentally opening? I've tied the gate to ground through R1, which seems correct.
- I've connected Vusb (gate) to VCC (drain), then added a diode to keep the MOSFET from always being open. Is this a correct assumption?
- Do I need any other diodes on the two power lines? I'd rather not have their voltage drop (otherwise I'd just use a simple ORing diode circuit to get what I want). What circumstances would produce backfeed current into either the battery or USB?
- I've often seen P-Channel MOSFETs connected the other way around, with the load connected to the source rather than the drain. What's the deal with that? Can current flow both directions? Which is most conventional?
- I'm planning to maybe use [FQP27P06](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/FQP27P06/FQP27P06-ND/965349?utm_adgroup=Semiconductor%20Modules&slid=&gclid=Cj0KCQiA-JXiBRCpARIsAGqF8wV5AH-cBDErh72mGw1h7OEzzeatjELHxT6s9yUbUQkDSWCXPxizPfYaAkFYEALw_wcB), though it seems most logic-level ones have a compatible Vgs(th) range. Have any better/cheaper suggestions?

Thanks again! I've asked multiple questions on this forum and y'all are always so helpful.

Comment: When the USB is disconnected the voltage at the transistor gate will not be 0, it will be equal to Vcc of the processor. Since you want Vcc to be close to Vbat the result will be that Vgs is close to zero, so  the PMOS never conducts. You simply can't connect Vcc to the transistor gate.

Comment: The transistor you linked does have a diode from drain to source, so if Vusb is 1.45V above Vbat you will get substantial current feeding back to the battery.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I was in the middle of correcting that when you must have posted. Could you take another look? I simply removed R1 because I'm not sure where to put it...

Comment: You need the pulldown to turn the transistor on when Vusb goes away. Worse, your modified schematic has no path for current from Vusb to Vcc. This question gets asked over and over here, try doing a more thorough search.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson ah good catch. I missed that. It seems the whole thing is just off because there's no way I can connect the USB to VCC without negative side effects (i.e. MOSFET never conducts). I'll take another whack at it later today. Perhaps this is just the answer I needed, that there is a glaring mistake with the original design. I'll put the R1 back just for clarity.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I've came back around and decided to add a diode D1 between gate and drain. This should fix the issue with the MOSFET never conducting, right?

Comment: Yes, I think that should work. Now you just need to think about current flowing back from Vusb to Vbat through the new diode and the drain-to-source diode of the MOSFET. You will probably start to see significant current flowing when Vusb is about 1V greater than Vbat. Sorry, I don't have a solution for that.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I see... I think I may just have to find a schottky and put it on the battery line. If that's the case, I might just end up using a good 'ol ORing diode configuration. I wanted to avoid diodes on the battery line, but it seems that may not  be possible.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson I suppose I could add a second MOSFET to the battery line by following this guy's technique: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrB-FPcv1Dc. At that point, it's a cost-benefit analysis of this over ORing diodes.

Comment: Yes, and with just 3 or 4 volts to work with for Vgs the voltage drop across the MOSFET might be comparable to a Schottky diode. Good luck.

Comment: I think I may be able to use the load-sharing circuit from the MCP73831/2 App Note, referenced in this SO question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293353/load-sharing-charging-circuit-for-lithium-polymer. It looks like this connects the load to the other side of the MOSFET.

Comment: Also @ElliotAlderson regarding the MOSFET voltage drop comment you made: wouldn't the MOSFET's body diode not be at play while the mosfet is conducting? (since resistance drops to RDSon).

Comment: No, the diode has its anode at the transistor's drain so it is reverse biased under normal conditions. The only time current will flow through the body diode is if the drain voltage is higher than the source voltage.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, can you take a look at the answer I posted?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was close, but this seems to be a working circuit, based on [this app note for a load-sharing circuit](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/AppNotes/01149c.pdf) and [this SO question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293353/load-sharing-charging-circuit-for-lithium-polymer). Essentially, I needed to reverse which side of the MOSFET the load goes on. See below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDsfQX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Analyzing this circuit...

When USB is connected, `Vs = Vg - Vf1 ==> Vg - Vs = Vf1 = Vgs`, where `Vf1` is the forward voltage drop across `D1`. Then `D1` can be selected such that its forward voltage falls under the `Vgs(th)` of the MOSFET, keeping it open. If `Vgs(th)` is about -2V to -4V (based on a typical logic-level P-Channel MOSFET), then we just need a diode with a drop of less than 2V, which is very easy. We also need to maintain as close to 5V as possible for the ATMEGA chip, so a schottky is best, as it can provide less than 1V drop.

When the USB is disconnected, `Vg` is pulled to 0V, and `Vs = Vcc = Vbat - Rds(on)*50mA` (for an approximate 50mA current). Thus `Vs` is close to 4.5V and `Vgs ~= -4.5V`, and the MOSFET will conduct. Selecting a MOSFET with a low `Rds(on)` will keep from losing too much voltage. The `D1` diode keeps the gate `Vg` from being equal to `Vs` at this point, as it will be reverse biased.

**Lingering questions...**

- One part that I'm not totally certain of is the scenario when the USB is disconnected: How can I assume that the MOSFET is conducting? It seems that if I start with that assumption, I don't run into any contradictions. Yet, if I assume that the MOSFET is open and `Vs = Vg = 0V`, then I don't really run into contradictions either. What would `Vs` be when in this second case? Perhaps someone can clarify? Otherwise, I'll assume that the folks who wrote the app note I'm referring to know what they're doing.

  **UPDATE - Answer:** When USB is unplugged, `Vg = 0V` and `Vs = Vd - Vf` where `Vd = Vbat` and `Vf` is the MOSFET's body diode forward voltage drop, usually around `0.65V` (note this is typically specified as `Vsd` on a datasheet and is usually given as a negative number). This puts `Vs ~= 3.85V`, resulting in `Vgs = Vg - Vs = -3.85V`. For a P-Channel MOSFET with a `Vgs(th)` of -2V to -4V, this will activate the MOSFET and cause it to conduct. Once the MOSFET has turned on, the voltage drop from the body diode goes away, and is replaced by the voltage drop from the internal resistance, called `Rds(on)`, so `Vs = Vd - Rds(on)*i` where `i` is the expected current through the MOSFET.

  > *Side Note:* Don't be confused by the fact that `Vgs(th)` is often a range on datasheets rather than a single value. It's totally fine and often desired to be more negative than the "max" for range (e.g. -4V in our case), within the datasheet's absolute max ratings, of course.
- Is `D2` necessary? If I understand correctly, it keeps current from backfeeding into the battery. The app note pictures it and mentions you can buy the MOSFET with it built-in (schottky). I manually added it to my schematic, but is it already assumed? i.e. is it the same or different from the parasitic body diode?

  **UPDATE - Answer:** It is the same as the body diode of the MOSFET and is not required as an "extra" diode. That said, some have [recommended against using it as the only backward-current protection diode](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/160179/77406).

Comment: The source of the PMOS should connect to the higher voltage (Vbat) rather than the lower voltage (Vcc). The symbol is shown correctly but your labels for Vs and Vd are reversed. When USB is connected Vg=Vusb so Vgs=Vusb-Vbat. When USB is not connected Vg=0 and Vgs=-Vbat. You are wasting a lot of power in R1...I would use 1k\$\Omega\$ or so.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson Ah, you're right. I also meant to make the resistor a 10K. I was in a bit of a rush posting this morning... Thanks.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson It's corrected. Any comments appreciated!

Comment: D2 is the body diode of the MOSFET; you don't need to add it as a discrete part. Btw that same diode might be important for the proper operation of the circuit at the moment the USB power is removed. It will take some miniscule time for the gate charge to dissipate through R1 (few microseconds probably), but during that time the MCU would only be powered from Vbatt through D2. When Vg gets to 0V, the P-MOS will conduct as expected. Be sure to have some more capacitance on the power supply pins of the MCU, 1µF or so, to cater for such transients.

Comment: Thank you @anrieff! Any thoughts about the first bullet? Namely why I can assume that Vs is not zero while the USB is disconnected.

Comment: For the same reason: Vd = Vbat, then Vs = Vd - 0.65V (the Vf of the body diode).

Comment: @anrieff That makes sense. However, that’s just for determining whether the MOSFET will close right? Once closed and conducting, the voltage drop across the S-D channel is determined by Rds(on) right?

Comment: That's correct. Be sure to select a MOSFET with low enough Rds(on) at the Vgs you'd be having - around -4.5V.

Comment: @anrieff I’m looking at the FQP27P06 by On/Fairchild as it seems popular for logic-level applications. Anything jump out that could be unfitting? One concern I have is that it says Vds is up to -4.0V! If I understand right, that could put Vs at nearly 0.5V and keep the MOSFET from closing right? (as it would give a Vgs of -0.5V and that’s far under the stated Vgs(th) of -2V to -4V...). I’d also be curious to know if this would need the extra capacitor you mentioned, as it’s stated to be fast for similar applications as mine.

Comment: FQP27P06 is not really logic level, it is optimized for being driven at Vgs = -10V. It would likely work, but the Rds(on) would be higher compared to a true logic level MOSFET. Better alternatives (e.g. IRLML6402) exist. As per the cap on the MCU - you need to have some anyway, e.g. 100nF, but having more would be better when you know the power supply can have small transients like this.

Comment: @anrieff Where did you get the 0.65V drop a few comments above? Could you elaborate on where in the datasheet it came from? If it was the graph, I’m a bit confused as the graph doesn’t line up with the 4V mentioned in the sheet for Vsd at the tested current. (Also, the MOSFET I mentioned actually has a pretty low Rds(on), at least for me).

Comment: A silicon diode has a typical forward voltage of about 0.65V, and of course that depends on the current thru it and temperature. The body diode (D2) is one silicon diode. It's exact characteristics in the FQP27P06, can be seen in Figure 4 on the datasheet ("Body Diode Forward Voltage Variation"). But the point is, if your P-MOS is off, Vs cannot be less than (Vd - 0.65V) (if it is, the body diode conducts). If the P-MOS is on, then Vs ≅ Vd (only resistive losses remain).

Comment: This is of course all greatly simplified and a lot of assumptions are made. I'd recommend you to get a nice circuit simulation tool (Circuit Lab on this site; or Falstad, or LTspice) and simulate the entire thing, I believe a lot of things will become more clear once you see them in action, and visualize the voltages at the various nodes.